# Calculating the equation of state parameter for matter

Tags: cosmology

am a grad student in a cosmology class right now and I've got something of a head scratcher.

"Assuming the velocity of the atomic particles can be described by a Maxwellian distribution, calculate the equation of state parameter, ω , of the matter. Recall that the Universe is, to first order, 75% Hydrogen and 25% Helium."

What I'm unsure about is this: I know how to use a Maxwellian distribution to, for instance, get the total number density of nonrelativistic particles (I can do this piecemeal for protons, neutrons, electrons, and then figure out how those talk to one another for 75% Hydrogen and 25% Helium assumption... I think). I figure I can use each number density to get an energy density using ε = nE = nmc² and then sum the energy densities. Maybe this is a long and convoluted way, I'm not sure (I suspect it might be because I'm getting eqns for Maxwellian distributions out of chapter 8 and we're in chapter 5 of the text, and they do not appear in the instructors lectures either. Perhaps there's a much simpler way to do this I just haven't thought of).

In any case, say I do get the energy density of matter under the problem's given assumptions. How would I relate this to an equation of state parameter ω? I'm given a temperature, 3000 K, but that's the only information I'm given. I know that P = ωε (but then I'd be left with "well what's P.")

I'm missing something fundamental here with my conception. I know a temperature, I know I'm doing something with a Maxwellian distribution of velocities, and somehow I'm supposed to end up with ω, and it seems the professor is expecting me to go beyond the material of the notes or as far as we've gotten in the text to do so because I promise there is nothing covered in either that would do this.

Ideas?